# String interpolation in PowerShell for an environment variable

Tags: powershell

I want to replace the path in this command:

```
$Env:PHANTOMJS_BIN='D:\michael\software\phantomjs-1.9.7-windows\phantomjs.exe'
```

With the output of this call:

```
Split-Path (Get-Command phantomjs).Path
```

Preferably using string interpolation. How is this possible in PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends whether you want to replace the variable just for the current session or permanent. Also machine-wide or for the user? Here an example to set the environment variable permanent for the machine:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PHANTOMJS_BIN", (Split-Path (Get-Command phantomjs).Path), [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

What do you mean with string interpolation?

Comment: The term "interpolation" may [come from Perl](http://www.perlmeme.org/howtos/using_perl/interpolation.html): *"Interpolation, meaning "introducing or inserting something", is the name given to replacing a variable with the value of that variable."*. But it is not clear what it means in the context of the question.

Comment: In any case, your question does not belong in the answer, but in a comment to the question ([Stack Overflow is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115)). Can you move it?